# Objectify - opposite of IN filter operation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Is there a way to exclude in the query when a list is filtered?
Something like: allow to fetch when the key is not inside keys list.

`List<Key<User>> userKeys = getUserKeys();
ofy().load().type(User.class).filter("__key__ ?????", userKeys).list();`

Answer (score 2):

This operation is not exposed by the low level api. File a feature request in the GAE issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list