# How to run an objectify filter NOT IN query?

Tags: objectify

I want to run a query in which I want to filter the set of users with @Id not present in a given collection of userIds.

eg :

```
ofy().load().type(User.class).filterKey("not in", list).iterator()
```

This type of query does not seem to run/be supported. 
Is it at all possible to run this ?

Comment: Asked before, but with no answer yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933012/objectify-opposite-of-in-filter-operation

Comment: Its been quite some time since that question. I hope someone has figured out something.

Comment: It has been 8 days since the author of objectify himself answered on that question that the operation cannot be supported by objectify because the low level api doesn't support it.